# iTunes stops playing song without reason

Tags: itunes, apple-music

I'm using Apple Music and I'm still in the evaluation period, but the system isn't working very well:

Either on my iPhone or my Mac (latest OS version), when I'm streaming music, it stops playing in an unexpected way after two minutes.

The playback play fine when the music is local, but connectivity is fine in other application. I wonder why *iTunes* is so buggy when it comes to distant request...

Comment: Are you saying that the music just stops? Does the app crash? Is it possibly a connectivity or bandwidth problem?

Comment: To add on to @AndrewEisenberg, if you download it offline does it happen too?

Comment: It seems to work offline so it's a connectivity issue. I'll update the post.

Comment: Post updated. I noticed Apple application (like iTune or App Store) are really slow when it comes to retrieve distant content. Safari runs fine.

Comment: I just updated to OS 10.11.6 El Capitan, and with local music files, I'm experiencing pauses like this too. Even when I'm not touching my keyboard/mouse I get these pauses.  It's as if the OS is phoning home and can't do anything whilst talking to mother.  I don't have any music in iCloud, so why would it do that?

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing. The app does not crash song just stops. When the music I am playing is downloaded onto my Iphone 7 plus (so I am not streaming) it will randomly stop playing and I have to start it again. To note: it also does this at times when I am streaming. I have the latest OS version as of 12/8/16 Ver 10.1.1. I also have a family member that has her Itunes do the same thing and she has the latest version of the IOS on her PC as well (I pay the family plan for Apple Music). From the searches I have done to see if this can be fixed it appears this has been a problem for so

Comment: @user214377 Take a look at my answer, hope it help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem by calling Apple hotline. They asked me to do a lot of manipulation and I cannot say precisely what was going wrong. We did a test on a new test user I created on the system. I started *iTunes*, connected my *Apple id* and *Apple Music* was working fine.

We removed together some *iTunes* configuration files and managed to restore *Apple Music* playback in my session.

Hope it helps!